# Error on starting processing in window 10 64bit

Tags: java, processing, startup

hello I used to used the Processing program.
(But I never used processing on this computer)
I have problem with starting Processing program.
I reinstalled java and jdk but it didn't work and I checked the file of processing but there was no wrong with it..

this is error window:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that this is just a program you're trying to run on your computer, and not something that you are developing right? It looks like there is an issue with the program that the developer needs to fix.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and redownloading Processing?

Comment: @Flaom yes it is it is.. but i need to use this..

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yes...I tried more then 5 times.

Comment: There is a disconnect between your assertion that "I checked the file of processing but there was no wrong with it." and the fact that the code is throwing an error. Please provide a [mcve]. It is impossible for us to debug code that we can't see. Something seems to be throwing a NullPointerException. The code that is doing so isn't included in your question, so there is really nothing more that can be said.

Comment: If there's a problem with the program, the most you can do is give the developer the screenshot you have on your post, and wait for it to be fixed. Perhaps you can try running the program on a different machine and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I checked with other computer and it worked! I think problem is my computer!

Comment: the problem is solved! If there is another file that name is "Processing" the programs path will corrupt. So, I deleted the file that name is Processing.